# Postgres union query returns strange result

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis

I have the following tables:

```
CREATE TABLE geodat(
vessel UUID NOT NULL,
trip UUID NOT NULL,
geom geometry(LineString,4326),

PRIMARY KEY(vessel,trip)
);

CREATE TABLE areas(
gid SERIAL NOT NULL,
/* --other columns of little interest-- */
geom geometry(MultiPolygon,3035),

PRIMARY KEY(gid)
);
```

The following query is supposed to return the area that has been crossed the least, as well as how many times it was crossed and by which vessels.

```
SELECT vessel,MIN(cnt) as min_crossing,gid
FROM (
    SELECT vessel,COUNT(*) as cnt, gid
    FROM (
        SELECT vessel, null as geo1, geom as geo2, null as gid
        FROM geodat

        UNION ALL

        SELECT null,geom,null,gid FROM areas ) as P
    WHERE ST_Crosses(geo1,geo2) AND geo1 IS NOT NULL AND geo2 IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY gid,vessel) as P1
GROUP BY gid,vessel
```

Theoretically, this query should solve the question above. The problem is that I am getting (0 rows) as an answer, although I have been assured as to the opposite. I discovered it has something to do with the null values the `UNION` produced, but I don't have a clue how to fix this.
Any ideas?

***NOTE:*** The two tables have 31822 rows and 27308 rows respectively which makes a `JOIN` impractical.

Comment: Why would a `JOIN` *be impratical*? The computational effort required to check that `WHERE ST_Crosses(geo1, geo2)` clause would be no different than using the condition as a JOIN clause (actually I believe you would get much better performances avoiding those useless subqieries). Have you created a GiST index on the geometry columns? Also, those null-checking conditions don't look like they would ever return true...

Comment: I initially tried to join the two tables `on ST_Crosses(geodat.geom,areas.geom)`. It resulted in my 6GB RAM getting filled up completely and the query seemed to be taking forever. I have created GiST indexes on both tables by the way. But you are probably right, there is little chance of these conditions being true for anything...

Comment: If you correctly defined an index on both tables and you have `VACUUM ANALYZE` them, those numbers look suspicious. Have you checked the output from `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`? Does the planner use the indexes? If yes, do you have any huge geometries in there? By *huge* I mean a geometry's bounding box intersects a large number of other geometries...

Comment: I have defined an index on the geometry column with the following statement: `CREATE INDEX ON geodat USING GiST(geom);` and `CREATE INDEX ON areas USING GiST(geom);`. The `VACUUM ANALYZE` has shown nothing wrong about either table. And it is likely that there is a huge number of intersections between geometries from `areas` and geometries of `geodat` but it can't be helped. The `areas` table's data are part of a dataset which was loaded as-is.

Comment: `VACUUM` is not supposed to show anything right or wrong, I asked about `EXPLAIN` which should show you the plan used to join the tables. Check if the indexes are actually being used. The next step is to check whether you set some *inappropriate* parameters in your postgresql.conf (compared to your machine and use case). As a last resort, you could think about *tiling* your huge areas before intersecting them, using some sort of CTE in your query of course. It's not the number of intersection that matters, but how efficiently they can be performed. In this sense, smaller geometries are better.

Comment: I ended up creating a new table with `areas` geometry column as a Polygon, using ST_ConcaveHull(geom,0.99). Worked pretty well, since the query now uses indexes and has a reduced time of execution (still long but not as long). Any way, I'd like to thank you for your answers; they have been illuminating.

Answer (score 0):

You have the condition

```
WHERE ST_Crosses(geo1,geo2) AND geo1 IS NOT NULL AND geo2 IS NOT NULL
```

However, in the `union all` you are explicitly setting `geo1` to `null` and `geo2` to `null`. Hence the query is returning `0` rows.
You can change the `where` condition above to `or`, which would return rows.

```
WHERE ST_Crosses(geo1,geo2) AND geo1 IS NOT NULL OR geo2 IS NOT NULL
```